# .Net MAUI Issue with VisualStateManager on Windows Platform

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, maui

I have created a simple .NET MAUI project that allows items to be selected in a CollectionView. What should happen is that the VisualStateManager should change the background colour to yellow for the selected item.  This works fine on the Android platform, but when I run against the Windows platform the selected item loses focus when the mouse cursor is moved away.

Is there a way to prevent the selected item from losing focus on the Windows platform?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SelectionTest.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter TargetName="valueLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Visual State Manager Sample" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Entry Text="Please subscribe to my channel!">
           
        </Entry>

        <CollectionView SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>111111111</x:String>
                    <x:String>222222222</x:String>
                    <x:String>333333333</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label x:Name="valueLabel" Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You say "the selected item loses focus when the mouse cursor is moved away". And what? What's the problem?

Comment: After clicking on the item to select it, the background changes colour.  The background should remain that colour even when the mouse cursor moves away from the control but it doesn’t.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works on Wndows as you expect...

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is that the `background color` should remain the selected color even when the mouse cursor moves away from the control on Windows, however it remains the selected background color on `Android`. In conclusion, the `VisualStateManager` works differently on `Windows` and `Android` so you can open a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) if needed.

However, I tested your code and the results on both platforms worked with no difference. I think you can try to change `SelectionMode="Multiple"` of CollectionView that will remain the selected color.

Comment: When you say the platforms worked the same with no difference, are you saying that the background colour remained the selected colour even when the mouse cursor moves away from the control? Or that the background colour was lost on both platforms when the mouse cursor leaves?

Comment: I mean the background color remained the selected color even when the mouse cursor moves away from the control.

Comment: BTW, may I know what version of VS you are using?

Comment: I tried a clean/rebuild but for the Windows platform build the selected colour still doesn't remain selected when moving the mouse cursor away.  I am using VS 2022 Pro (17.4.2) on Windows 11.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue based on your code. You can open a new issue:https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/new if you think it's a potential issue.

Comment: I have opened an issue as you suggest and will report back with any findings.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Feel free to get back here if you need any help!